# Use a method as producer in camel route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have method which every now and then generates a string. I would like to register method as uri and produce a exchange method which will be used as input for a route.

The method is call by a different class

```
SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
sc.sampleMethod("Hello");
```

Eg:

```
public class SampleClass{
    @Produce(uri = "direct:consumerMethod")
    ProducerTemplate producer;
    public sampleMethod(Object obj){
          producer.sendBody(object);
    }
}
```

The route is defined as below:

```
@Override
    public void configure() {
        from("direct:consumerMethod").process(new GenerateD());
    }
```

But the route doesnt call GenerateD class when i produce using the sampleMethod. Is this not feasible or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe the parameter for `.process(...)` needs to be a `Processor` or inherit/implement it - Inside your processor, you then could call your method.  I am nowhere near my sample code but this might nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I put a try catch around producer.sendBody() and found producer is null. So does this mean direct:consumerMethod is not started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is what worked for my use case.

Starting camelcontext as below:

```
CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
camelContext.addRoutes(new SampleRoute());
camelContext.start();
```

My routebuilder class :

```
    class SampleRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        try
        {
            from("direct:consumerMethod").process(new DDT());
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I then create a interface which has a sendMessage method.

```
public interface DDTConsumer {

    public String sendMessage(Object object);

}
```

Now i implement this method to create an endpoint of this interface and send a message to the endpoint.

```
DDTConsumer ddt;
try {
    ddt = new ProxyBuilder(camelContext).endpoint("direct:consumerMethod").build(DDTConsumer.class);
    ddt.sendMessage(msg.getValue());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This solved my problem and the route is working fine now. Hope it helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your class where you have the `sampleMethod(Object)` add the following field:

```
@Produce(uri = "direct:consumerMethod")
ProducerTemplate template;
```

In your `sampleMethod(Object)` you can use the previously added `template` like this:

```
public sampleMethod(Object obj){
      template.sendBody(object);
}
```

And it should send a Message to the `direct:consumerMethod` route.

Comment: If u see my code it is already doing that.Yet the process is not getting called.

Comment: Are you sure that the `direct:consumerMethod` route started? Do you use Camel with Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this, if you want to call somemethod

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    from("direct:consumerMethod").log(simple("${bean:generateD?method=generateDMethod}"));
}
```

The above expression will call the `generateDMethod` of `generateD` object (bean) and log the methods output to console (the default log writer).
To make above expression work, you have to store `generateD` bean in the Registry, which will be further associated with your application's CamelContext. You can do the same as follows

```
@Autowired
private GenerateD generateD;

@Override
protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
    SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry(); 
    registry.put("generateD", generateD); //the generateD bean,which can be used anywhere in the camelcontext
    SpringCamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext();
    camelContext.setRegistry(registry); //add the registry
    camelContext.setApplicationContext(getApplicationContext());
    camelContext.start();
    return camelContext;
}
```

This adds the bean to camelContext. Please check my answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009438/rest-service-call-with-camel-which-requires-authentication-api-called-first/45138669#45138669) to have complete example.