# Calling a REST API with Camel that requires a separate authentication request for a token

Tags: rest, apache-camel

Many APIs requires a separate call to an authentication server to retrieve a token (and sometimes a primary host) used to make the primary request. Some APIs intend for you to make this preliminary call for each primary request, but others expect you to store the token and use it for all your requests over a period of time.

For my process, I'm receiving a payload from a queue that I need to translate into the API request. This part is easy with Camel. But for the first authentication approach, where you make an auth request for each primary request, I don't see how to preserve the request after I make the call to the authorization server.

For the second auth approach, there is an example here of preserving the token: [REST service call with Camel which requires authentication api called first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009438/rest-service-call-with-camel-which-requires-authentication-api-called-first)

This looks pretty complicated for a pretty common integration scenario. Are there better examples of how to achieve these two methods with Came?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking to something like this (intuitive solution, not tested at all!).

The trick would be to make a "In-Only" call to auth server (to keep original request), and put the obtained token in a property, so that the next call (to the API) can use it:

```
from("direct:demo")
    .to("direct:getAuthToken?exchangePattern=InOnly")
    .header("Authorization").simple("Bearer ${exchangeProperty.myToken}")
    .to("http://app-server/api/ws")
    .log("Response: ${body}")

from("direct:getAuthToken") 
    ...
    .to("http://iam-server/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token")
    .property("myToken").jsonpath("$.access_token")
```

Of course, this could be easily optimised by caching the obtained token in order to avoid unnecessary calls to the identity server.

Not sure it will work, but this may give you some inspiration.

Comment: I'm experimenting with this, but it looks like I lose the message body after .to("direct:getAuthToken?exchangePattern=InOnly"), even though it's set to InOnly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar demand and not implemented a solution, yet.

In order not to loose the original Exchange, `enrich` seems to be the better way for calling the route for fetching the token.
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/eips/enrich-eip.html

```
from("direct:demo")
    .enrich("direct:getAuthToken?exchangePattern=InOnly", aggregationStrategy)
    .header("Authorization").simple("Bearer ${exchangeProperty.myToken}")
    .to("http://app-server/api/ws")
    .log("Response: ${body}")
```

You would also have to implement an AggregationStrategy or use a predefined one.